# TCHAR variable truncation in VS 2017 with AutoCAD 2019

Tags: c, visual-c++, character-encoding

When compiling my older objectarx code with Visual Studio 2017 and testing with AutoCAD 2019, the following function prints just `fname = T` instead of the whole `fname = TestFileName` when calling my own function `acad_printf`. This problem does not occur when calling `ads_printf` or `acutPrintf` directly. I had never problem with this in previous versions. `tchar.h` included, `TCHAR` typed as `wchar_t`, `TILE_STR_LIMIT` is 2035.

```
    void acad_printf (const TCHAR *fmt, ...)
/*****************************************/

{
  TCHAR buf[500];
  va_list parg;

  va_start(parg, fmt);  /* Initialize variable arguments. */
  _vstprintf(buf,fmt,parg);
  ads_printf(_T("%.130s"),buf);
  va_end(parg);  
}

void test (void)
{

    TCHAR fname[TILE_STR_LIMIT] = _T("TestFileName");

    acad_printf(_T("\nfname = %s"), fname);
}
```

Comment: How are `_UNICODE` and `_MBCS` defined`?

Comment: _UNICODE defined, _MBCS undefined

Answer (score 1):

Format %s was invalid, %ls is needed in

```
acad_printf(_T("\nfname = %ls"), fname);
```